# how to use "make mrproper " command? i am working on Linux From Scratch 

Tags: linux, bash, gcc, makefile, linux-from-scratch

I am trying to build Linux From Scratch and I have reached till this part : [linux headers](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/6.6/chapter05/linux-headers.html)

> Make sure there are no stale files and dependencies lying around from previous activity:

```
make mrproper
```

I don't understand: in which directory should I run this command? In one of these?

```
$LFS/sources/gcc-build
$LFS/sources/gcc-4.4.3
```

Please Help!

Comment: Not familiar with LFS, but usually, this would be in /usr/src/linux

Comment: Each tarball is extracted to its own directory. If the webpage heading is "File-ver", you cd to the directory that file-ver.tar.gz was extracted to, which is usually named the same as the tarball, except without the .tar.gz extension. You cd to that new directory and execute the commands in that directory. This is true for all LFS build instructions unless otherwise noted in the instructions.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should run that (an the following) in the directory where you unpacked the kernel source tarball.

Comment: u mean $LFS/sources/linux-2.6.32.8/
i have to cd there and run make mrproper?

EDIT: thnx man , it seems to work .......

Answer (score 0):

That comes **after** gcc use

```
cd $LFS/sources
tar xvjf linux*
cd linux*
make mproper
make headers_check
make INSTALL_HDR_PATH=dest headers_install
cp -rv dest/include/* /tools/include
```

cd $LFS/sources tells it to change to the sources directory.
tar xvjf linux* tells it to untar the lunix api headers directory (the j in xvjf might be a capital)
cd linux* tells it to go to the untared directory
make mproper is a special use of the make command to specially make this directory
 make headers_check
    make INSTALL_HDR_PATH=dest headers_install
    cp -rv dest/include/* /tools/include tells it to install and test the package

Answer (score 0):

Running `make mrproper` or `make distclean` returns the kernel source tree to its unconfigured state. This means you loose your .config file. You will need to create a new .config file before compiling the kernel.